# asp.net mvc 3 url routing with name of news

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a news website. I usually use parameter to to display a news or browser category of news. For example:

http://mysite.com/News/Details/5

**News** is controller - 
**Details** is action -
**5** is Id of news

Now I want to add name of this news into Url. For example:

**http://mysite.com/News/Details/5/name-of-news/**
or 
**http://mysite.com/News/name-of-news/**

for paging, I also use parameter
http://mysite.com/News?page=2

now I want to my url display as following url
**http://mysite.com/News/Page1**

How can I do these thing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paging is usually (and I also recommend it) done using query parameters as `?page=1` because it barely displays a filtered result of a known collection within REST request which can be different over time. Collection as itself is always the same so it's valid within REST spec.

Comment: Having news accessible by name only is also not desired because of title changes. ID is always static but title can change which makes Google results invalid. When using ID+title it's also wise to use `META` canonical info to distinguish these multifacets of the same page content.

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel N, I display my product by using "/Product/Details/id". I also want to 

add name of product into Url, but when I add one more MapRoute, It always run MapRoute 

of news. How can I resolve this issue ? @Robert Koritnik: Thanks for your comments. Do 

you have any link talk about this ? I want to know more. Thanks.

Comment: The order routing mapping matters you are supposed to put more specific routes at the top. Swap the two mappings and see what you are getting.

Comment: @CamDiep: If you'd like to learn more about `rel="canonical"` then this [Google resource](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394&&hl=en) is your best start. BTW: It's not `meta` but rather `link`. Sorry for misinfo.

Answer (score 2):

Add news to a list of parameters your action takes

```
        ActionResult Details(string id,string newsName){
        }
        //add a routing map 
         routes.MapRoute(
            "NewsDetailsIdName",                                             
            "{News}/{Details}/{id}/{newsName}",                           
            new { controller = "News", action = "Details"}  
         );

      or 
       //If news name is unique
       ActionResult Details(string newsName){
       }
      //Add a routing map
       routes.MapRoute(
            "NewsDetailsName",                                             
            "{News}/{Details}/{newsName}",                           
            new { controller = "News", action = "Details"}  
       );
```

For pagging, add a routing map on your news Index action

```
        ActionResult Index(string page){
        }
        //Add a route
        routes.MapRoute(
            "NewsPage",                                             
            "{News}/{page}",                           
            new { controller = "News", action = "Index"}  
        );
```